# JPA QueryDSL: count() leads to ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle, jpa, querydsl

I have the following Query, which tries to find the count of all RUNNING Trackings:

```
new JPAQuery(getEntityManager()).from(myTracking)
            .where(myTracking.trackingStatus.isNotNull(),
            myTracking.trackingStatus.eq(TrackingStatus.RUNNING))
            .count()
```

This leads to ORA-01722: invalid number. Why?

EDIT: Logging of the SQL statement:

```
    /* select
    count(myTracking) 
from
    MyTracking myTracking 
where
    myTracking.trackingStatus is not null 
    and myTracking.trackingStatus = ?1 */ select
        count(mytrackin0_.ID) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        owner.T_my_TRACKING mytrackin0_ 
    where
        (
            mytrackin0_.STATUS is not null
        ) 
        and mytrackin0_.STATUS=?
```

Comment: maybe looking at the SQL generated would tell you ?

Comment: look in the log for whatever software sends the query, so QueryDSL perhaps

Comment: Which Querydsl version you use? And which JPA provider? It looks like an issue with the enum eq ? part.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments! I just found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is I forgot to add the @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) to my Enum attribute.

```
MyEntity{
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TrackingStatus trackingStatus;
}
```

This was resulting in the Enum-Position and NOT the Enum-String beeing inserted into the Database-Column.
     Once I added the annotation the still running trackings in the database were compared with their Enum-Position to the Enum-String from the query -> ORA-01722: invalid number.
The solution was to delete/migrate the few wrong mapped trackings.